# Python Run 2 classes at the same time then 2 other classes at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a script with many classes, let say i have 100 class for example

When i try to run all of them at the same time (parallel), i got out of memory and my script got killed.

Here is an example of how my script is structured :

```
from threading import *

class Test1(Thread):
def run(self):
    print("done1")

Test1().start()

class Test2(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print("done2")


Test2().start()

class Test3(Thread):
def run(self):
    print("done3")

Test3().start()

class Test4(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print("done4")


Test4().start()
```

With this code, the script run Test1() Test2() Test3() and Test4() at the same time (parallel).

What i'm looking for is to run Test1() and Test2() at the same time (parallel) and wait until they finish then run Test3() and Test4() parallel.

How can i do that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a few approaches here. You can use [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) and schedule a set number of threads:

```
import os
import random
import time

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

THREADS = os.cpu_count()


class WorkerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, idx):
        super().__init__()

        self.q = q
        self.idx = idx

    def run(self):
        for num in iter(self.q.get, "STOP"):
            t = random.uniform(1, 5)
            print(f"START (THREAD: {self.idx})")
            time.sleep(t)
            print(f"END   (THREAD: {self.idx}), RESULT: {num * num}")


def main():
    q = Queue()

    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)

    threads = []

    for i in range(THREADS):
        t = WorkerThread(q, i)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for _ in range(THREADS):
        q.put("STOP")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test1.py 
START (THREAD: 0)
START (THREAD: 1)
START (THREAD: 2)
START (THREAD: 3)
START (THREAD: 4)
START (THREAD: 5)
START (THREAD: 7)
START (THREAD: 6)
END   (THREAD: 6), RESULT: 36
START (THREAD: 6)
END   (THREAD: 0), RESULT: 0
START (THREAD: 0)
END   (THREAD: 5), RESULT: 25
END   (THREAD: 4), RESULT: 16
END   (THREAD: 1), RESULT: 1
END   (THREAD: 3), RESULT: 9
END   (THREAD: 7), RESULT: 49
END   (THREAD: 6), RESULT: 64
END   (THREAD: 2), RESULT: 4
END   (THREAD: 0), RESULT: 81
```

Alternatively you can use [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) module that provides a high-level interface. The [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) object will create a pool of workers:

```
import random
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def worker(num):
    t = random.uniform(1, 5)
    print(f"START ({num})")
    time.sleep(t)

    return num * num


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for result in executor.map(worker, range(10)):
            print(f"RESULT: {result}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```